# Barplot with sorted dots

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart

I want to plot a 4 group barplot from a first data-frame called df1 and display dots from another data-frame called df2. The idea is to check how many dots from df2 lie outside of df1.

So I made the following graph which works well.

```
### 0- Import package
library(dplyr)
    
### 1- Data simulation
set.seed(4)
df1 <- data.frame(var=c("a", "b", "c", "d"), value=c(15, 19, 18, 17))
df2 <- data.frame(var1=rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each=20), value=rnorm(80, 15, 2), color=NA, fill=NA)

### 2- Coloring data (outside=red, inside=blue)
df2$fill <- case_when(
  (df2$var1=="a" & df2$value>subset(df1, var=='a')$value) ~ "#e18b8b", 
  (df2$var1=="b" & df2$value>subset(df1, var=='b')$value) ~ "#e18b8b", 
  (df2$var1=="c" & df2$value>subset(df1, var=='c')$value) ~ "#e18b8b", 
  (df2$var1=="d" & df2$value>subset(df1, var=='d')$value) ~ "#e18b8b", 
  TRUE ~ "#8cbee2")
df2$color <- case_when(
  (df2$var1=="a" & df2$value>subset(df1, var=='a')$value) ~ "#ca0d0d", 
  (df2$var1=="b" & df2$value>subset(df1, var=='b')$value) ~ "#ca0d0d", 
  (df2$var1=="c" & df2$value>subset(df1, var=='c')$value) ~ "#ca0d0d", 
  (df2$var1=="d" & df2$value>subset(df1, var=='d')$value) ~ "#ca0d0d", 
  TRUE ~ "#0c78ca")

### 3- Display plot
ggplot(aes(x=var, y=value), data=df1) + geom_bar(stat="identity", fill='#8cbee2', width=0.6) + 
  geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=var1, y=value), colour=df2$color, fill=df2$fill, position=position_jitter(width=0.05, height=0), shape=21, size=2)
```

[image]

In order to improve this graph, I would like to order dots from df2 displayed within each barplot group, kind of qqplot-shaped.
-First, this would allow to tell whether the amount of dots outside is huge or not compared to barplots.
-Second, this would allow to see distribution of inside & outside dots.

I have found the following link but it only deals with one data-frame and I am working with 2.
[How to plot boxplots superimposed with sorted points using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66809733/how-to-plot-boxplots-superimposed-with-sorted-points-using-ggplot2)

[image]

Do you have any clue on how to sort these dots?

**EDIT**
Result following Stephan's answer

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to use `position_dodge` and a helper column. To this end first order your data by `var1` and `value`, then add the helper column as an `interaction` of `var1` and the row index or number. This helper column could then be mapped on the `group` aes to ensure that points are plotted in ascending order where the dodge gives the qqplot-like shape:

Note: I also used a different approach for the colors which uses a `left_join` and maps on the `color` and `fill` aes.

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(4)
df1 <- data.frame(var = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), value = c(15, 19, 18, 17))
df2 <- data.frame(var1 = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each = 20), value = rnorm(80, 15, 2), color = NA, fill = NA)

df2 <- df2 %>%
  left_join(df1, by = c("var1" = "var"), suffix = c("", "_df1")) %>%
  arrange(var1, value) %>%
  mutate(
    var_dodge = interaction(var1, row_number()),
    color = value > value_df1
  )

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(aes(x = var, y = value), data = df1) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#8cbee2", width = 0.6) +
  geom_point(
    data = df2, aes(x = var1, y = value, group = var_dodge, color = color, fill = color),
    position = position_dodge(width = .4), shape = 21, size = 2
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "#ca0d0d", "FALSE" = "#0c78ca")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "#e18b8b", "FALSE" = "#8cbee2")) +
  guides(fill = "none", color = "none")
```

[image]